# How do I append/prepend list in function without modifying source?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, defensive-copy

Given this source list:

```
source_list = [2, 3, 4]
```

and this function:

```
def function(list_in):
    list_in.append(5)
    list_in.insert(0, 1)
    return list_in
```

As expected, I get:

```
>>> function(source_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But if I call the variable source_list outside of the function I still get:

```
>>> source_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there an alternative way of modifying (specifically appending/prepending to) a list within a function such that the original list is not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the function, you can copy the list passed:

like this:

```
def function(list_in_):     # notice the underscore suffix
    list_in = list_in_[:]   # copy the arg into a new list
    list_in.append(5)
    list_in.insert(0, 1)
    return list_in          # return the new list
```

otherwise you can call the function with a copy of your `source_list`, and decide if you want a new list, or if you prefer the `source_list` mutated, as demonstrated by @tdelaney

Answer (score 2):

If you are the caller of the function, you can copy first

```
new_list = function(source_list[:])
```

This has the advantage that the caller decides whether it wants its current list to be modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copy()` method on the list:

```py
new_list = function(source_list.copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

Add just a line to your function:

```
   def function(list_n):
    #Do a copy of your list
    list_in = list_n.copy()
    list_in.append(5)
    list_in.insert(0, 1)
    return list_in
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Since the source list is modified while running the function in your code you are not able to retain the source list.

```
source_list = [2, 3, 4]
list_in=source_list.copy()
def function(list_in):
    list_in.append(5)
    list_in.insert(0, 1)
    return list_in
print(function(list_in))
print(source_list)
```